# python - splitting string by first occurrence of Alpha character

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

I have a list of string like follow (each line is a string variable)

```
6.40 D5
8.45 F5
9.00 E5
10.30 D5
12.30 E5
13.00HUm5 <-- outlier, without space
13.15 F5
15.05 F5
15.45 Fm5
```

I simply want to split the **time** (the front one) from the **attribute** (the back one).

This can be simply achieved by `str.split()`.

However, the problem is that there may be a case about an outlier string like `13.00HUm5`, where there are no white space between time and attribute.

It will fail if I use the code above.

I want it to be `['13.00', 'HUm5']`

How can I tell the code to *split the string when an Alpha characters appears after a Digit characters* ?

Is it possible to achieve something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = """6.40 D5
8.45 F5
9.00 E5
10.30 D5
12.30 E5
13.00HUm5
13.15 F5
15.05 F5
15.45 Fm5"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    m = re.match(r"(\d+\.\d+)\s*(.*)$", line)
    if m:
        print([m.group(1), m.group(2)])
```

**Output:**

```
['6.40', 'D5']
['8.45', 'F5']
['9.00', 'E5']
['10.30', 'D5']
['12.30', 'E5']
['13.00', 'HUm5']
['13.15', 'F5']
['15.05', 'F5']
['15.45', 'Fm5']
```